How to bring back Nextjs 15 static indicator
I’m using Nextjs 15 and it now has a static route indicator see image:
(i cant post images :< )
(https://i.sstatic.net/fbsD3a6t.jpg)
But when I hovered in it and an x appeared and I closed it and now its gone. I tried googling this but I found nothing. Is there any way to bring back? Thanks stack overflow!
I tried googling it, restart dev server and restart my pc but to no avail.

From the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/devIndicators#appisrstatus-static-indicator

You can temporarily hide the indicator by clicking the close indicator which will remember your preference in localStorage for 1 hour.

Steps to clear your local storage:

npm run dev or whatever your package manager.
Go to localhost:3000 and inspect the page.
Go to Storage then to Local Storage then to http://localhost:3000
Right click and select Delete All.

After that it should appear again.

It's stored in LocalStorage.
In Chrome:

Inspect your code (right click on web-page, Inspect)
Select the Application-Tab
Select LocalStorage in the Sidebar and select your domain, e.g. localhost:3000
Delete the setting from the storage with the cross icon


